SQL query to export data in excel anda update columns written in Excel
I would like to know if it is possible and, broadly speaking, how to perform a daily extraction from Microsoft Navision into an Excel file using SQL.
Specifically:
About 15 columns are standard fields from Navision that need to be extracted into Excel.
Additionally, 4 columns are manually filled in Excel, and these must remain stored within the file so that they are not lost during subsequent extractions. These additional columns include both "Date" fields and "Yes/No" fields.
I aim to perform two automatic daily extractions. Even if someone is working on the shared Excel file, the same data should still be updated.
To clarify, here are the fields to be extracted from Navision:
Order Number, Order Line, Customer Reference, Account Manager, 
Customer Code, Customer Name, Country, Sales Item Code, Item Code, 
Description, Cross Reference, Payment Terms

And here are the fields that departments need to add manually:
YES/NO, DATE - Technical Data Completed, YES/NO, YES/NO

Thank you in advance for any responses or guidance!

Friendly advice. Don't do that. First of all it is an ugly solution. Second, you won't be able to write to excel file if it is opened. Unless it is on SharePoint or something, but this is a completely another story.

Thanks, and what's the suggestion? thanks in advance.

You can have 2 xls files. First - for data extraction from Navision by your query. Second - for manual edits. In Second - you can connect (formula or table) to First and take data while needed (refresh source).

Ok thanks for the update. But the second day of the extraction how can i compare the value in the Excel with the extracted new value, update or add new Orders and keep the comments? Thanks

Just add these fields to Navision
